# Typoscript - Conditional tags around <html> as in html5boilerplate

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, html5boilerplate

Im trying to get this lines at the beginning of the document

```
<!doctype html public "✰">
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ....
```

coming from the html5boilerplate.

How can I do this with typoscript?

I had tried

```
config.doctype = html_5
```

and this works alright to use the clean meta char, but I cant add the conditionals

on the other hand there is this option: http://typo3.toaster-schwerin.de/typo3_english/2011_03/msg00014.html but then I lose the "clean" charset and have the longer and uglier one.

I know that it doesnt really make a difference, but i would like if I could have the short version of the meta charset tag.

Is there a way to have it all?

Comment: http://typo3.toaster-schwerin.de/typo3_english/2011_03/msg00014.html

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my problem with the meta charset tag. I have edited the question. Now you'll see why that solution isnt EXACTLY what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the extension html5boilerplate ([EXT:html5boilerplate in TER](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/html5boilerplate/current/)).

It supports the conditional comments which are also configurable via an option in the [TypoScript setup](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/html5boilerplate/ExtHtml5Boilerplate/TyposcriptSetup/ConfigurationSetup(confightml5boilerplate)/Index.html)

Comment: Yes, Ive looked at it. But I dont want to install the whole boilerplate. I just want to conditionals around the html. But im not sure how they do it.

Comment: They do it by a hook: https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/html5boilerplate/current/info/Classes%252Fclass.tx_html5boilerplate.php/

Comment: 404 on Typoscript Setup link

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it;

(I found the answer somewhere while searching but can not remember where)

```
# conditional comments around HTML tag
config {
    htmlTag_stdWrap {
        setContentToCurrent = 1
        cObject = COA
        cObject {
            temp = TEXT
            temp.addParams.class = no-js
            temp.append = TEXT
            temp.append.char = 10
            temp.current = 1

            10 < .temp
            10.addParams.class = no-js ie6 ltie8 ltie9 ltie10
            10.wrap = <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>|<![endif]-->

            20 < .temp
            20.addParams.class = no-js ie7 ltie8 ltie9 ltie10 iefix
            20.wrap = <!--[if IE 7 ]>|<![endif]-->

            30 < .temp
            30.addParams.class = no-js ie8 ltie9 ltie10 iefix
            30.wrap = <!--[if IE 8 ]>|<![endif]-->

            40 < .temp
            40.addParams.class = no-js ie9 ltie10
            40.wrap = <!--[if IE 9 ]>|<![endif]-->

            50 < .temp
            50.wrap = <!--[if !(IE)]><!--> | <!--<![endif]-->
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using typoscript conditions?

```
config.htmlTag_setParams = class="no-js"
[browser = < msie7]
config.htmlTag_setParams = class="no-js ie6 oldie"
[global]
[browser = msie7]
config.htmlTag_setParams = class="no-js ie7 oldie"
[global]
[browser = msie8]
config.htmlTag_setParams = class="no-js ie8 oldie"
[global]
```